# How to proof that smooth function vanishing on xy-coordinates cross must be of form $xyg$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, smooth-functions

I am reading Jet Nestruev's Smooth Manifolds and Observables book and I am struggling with the exercise 2.12. It states that any smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ vanishing on coordinate cross $K=\{x=0\}\cup\{y=0\}$ must be of form $f(x,y)=xyg(x,y)$ for some smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

The exercise is states just after [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma), so I guess I should use it or related ideas somehow.

---

EDIT. I just managed to prove that

$$f(x,y)=x\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(tx, y)dt \\
f(x,y)=y\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, ty)dt$$

Thus $f(x,y)=xg_1(x,y)=yg_2(x,y)$. However, I now stuck there.

---

EDIT 2. Ok, I guess I know the answer. Since $f$ vanishes on the cross $K$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ vanishes on $x$-axis. Thus we can apply the same argument as previously and obtain that

$$f(x,y)=xy\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(tx, sy)dsdt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Hadamard's lemma, $f(x,y) = x\phi(x,y)$ for some smooth $\phi$. Since $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$, we deduce that $\phi(x,0)=0$ for all $x$ and hence $\phi(x,y)=yh(x,y)$ for some smooth $h$. Thus, $f(x,y)=xyh(x,y)$.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more this after "Thus"? I just figured something out (I will make a new edit in a second). I am not sure if there is an algebraic argument that given element from principal ideals generated by $x$ and $y$ must be in the principal ideal generated by $xy$.

Comment: We're applying Hadamard first to $f$ and then to $\phi$. The "thus" is just mere substitution. I do not understand why you keep going back to the proof. Just apply the lemma itself.

Comment: OOO, I misread the answer. You are right.

Comment: Sometimes we miss the most obvious things :)